# OneHotEncoder striping headers

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to make an ML model in the titanic dataset and while preparing it I used OneHotEncoder to make Embarked dummies and while doing that I lost my column headers.
Here is how the dataset looked before.

```
Pclass  Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Fare    Cabin   Embarked
0   3   1   22.000000   1   0   7.2500  146 2
1   1   0   38.000000   1   0   71.2833 81  0
2   3   0   26.000000   0   0   7.9250  146 2
3   1   0   35.000000   1   0   53.1000 55  2
4   3   1   35.000000   0   0   8.0500  146 2
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
886 2   1   27.000000   0   0   13.0000 146 2
887 1   0   19.000000   0   0   30.0000 30  2
888 3   0   29.699118   1   2   23.4500 146 2
889 1   1   26.000000   0   0   30.0000 60  0
890 3   1   32.000000   0   0   7.7500  146 1
```

Here is the code.

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [7])], remainder='passthrough')
X = pd.DataFrame(ct.fit_transform(X))
X
```

Here is how the dataset is looking now.

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
0   1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 3.0 1.0 22.000000   1.0 7.2500  146.0
1   0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 38.000000   1.0 71.2833 81.0
2   1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 3.0 0.0 26.000000   0.0 7.9250  146.0
3   1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 35.000000   1.0 53.1000 55.0
4   1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 3.0 1.0 35.000000   0.0 8.0500  146.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
886 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 27.000000   0.0 13.0000 146.0
887 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 19.000000   0.0 30.0000 30.0
888 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 3.0 0.0 29.699118   1.0 23.4500 146.0
889 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 26.000000   0.0 30.0000 60.0
890 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 3.0 1.0 32.000000   0.0 7.7500  146.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `get_feature_names` method of `ColumnTransformer`, provided all your transformers support that method and you've trained on a dataframe.

```py
ct = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [7])], remainder='passthrough')
X = pd.DataFrame(ct.fit_transform(X), columns=ct.get_feature_names())
X
```

Comment: By default, new column names are like encoder__x0_0. What should I do to make them the same as the categorical variables?

Comment: Ah, right, that's an unfortunate problem with the current implementation.  `OneHotEncoder.get_feature_names` requires a parameter `input_features` for the "base" names, but `ColumnTransformer.get_feature_names` doesn't work with that.  (They've been working on various approaches to feature names, so hopefully soon this will work more smoothly.)  You can hack something together by monkey-patching or wrapping a custom class around `OneHotEncoder`; more basic, I suppose, you can just rename the columns with a regexp replacement of `x{i}` with your column names.

Answer (score 0):

output of [fit_transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.fit_transform) is array like
`X_t{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, sum_n_components)`
(not DataFrame-like)

Thus no Headers. If you want headers, you'll have to name them when rebuilding the DataFrame.